# View navigations in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, view

I want to implement the view navigations application using Swift.View navigations are like when user click on one button it navigates to the next view.

Can any one provide the sample example for view navigations inSwift language.

Comment: I want the sample code for view navigations in Swift

Comment: i got the solution. gofer editor option and select the Embedded in option and click on navigationController.Navigation controller will be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code for navigation from `rootViewController` to `SecondViewController`:

```
let secondViewController : SecondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View2") as SecondViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Put this code where you want to perform this action also dont forget to create `SecondVoewController` Into your storyBoard.

For more Information you can refer [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQXWsDNno8o) tutorial.